# How to split a sequence into every 3 neighbor elements in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Given a sequence like:

```
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

How to split it into every 3 neighbor elements in clojure? Just like the following:

```
([1 2 3] [2 3 4] [3 4 5] [4 5 6])
```

Functions in clojure.core are preferred!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [partition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition):

```
user=> (partition 3 1 [1 2 3 4 5 6])
((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5) (4 5 6))
```